diferenças de termos matemáticos do português do Brasil e do português de Portugal
Estou tentando pesquisar diferenças linguísticas de termos matemáticos no Brasil e em Portugal.
Exemplo 1: dezesseis (mais usado no Brasil) dezasseis (mais usado em Portugal)
Exemplo 2: No Brasil, 1 bilhão equivale a 1.000.000.000.
Em Portugal: 1 bilhão equivale a         1.000.000.000.000.
Existem outros exemplos ou trabalhos que já tenham feito tal compilação?

Se eu não me engano não é uma questão de ortografia, mas devido a adoção por todos países europeus, algo que não foi seguido por países como Brasil e EUA, o que é quase independente do idioma.

@Chigurh, naão entendo o seu comentário ...

Se eu não estiver enganado, o bilião (bilhão) no Brasil e bilion no EUA equivalem a 10⁹, enquanto nos países europeus foi adotado 10¹² para bilião, ou seja, é uma questão de "medida" adotada e não de ortografia, semelhante a adoção do sistema métrico. Para ficar mais claro, é um uso científico que define isso, e cabe aos países adotarem a norma, segue mais detalhes: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escalas_curta_e_longa. Vou formular uma resposta, mesmo que o assunto seja ciencias, porque parece util ao site

Mas será que seguem a isso em Portugal? Sei que o seguem na Alemanha e acho que na Rússia, mas acho que não o seguem na Inglaterra, por exemplo.

@Schilive os países que usam um, ou outro, ou ambas, estão descritos no link do wikipedia que enviei no comentário anterior.

@Chigurh, é verdade. Obrigado. Ainda seria legal ter um português afirmando sua experiência.

@Chigurh, confirmo em Portugal sempre me ensinaram que um bilião = um milhão de milhões = 10¹²

@JJoao, e mesmo na língua corrente 1 bilhão = 1 milhão de milhões? Então, em Portugal, diz-que no mundo há 7 milhões de milhões de pessoas?

@Schilive:  7 mil milhões ou 7 milhares de milhões de pessoas.  Ou ainda 7 x 10^9 pessoas.

@JJoao, eu errei um pouco as conta'. Interessante! Obrigado.

mais alguns casos para a coleção:
num               : br                  : pt
14                : quatorze ou catorze : catorze
16                : dezesseis           : dezasseis;
17                : dezessete           : dezassete;
19                : dezenove            : dezanove;
1 000 000 000     : um bilião ou bilhão : um milhar de milhão ou mil milhões
1 000 000 000 000 : trilião ou trilhão  : um bilião
0                 : zero gato ou gatos  : zero gatos

Por favor corrijam se houver erros.

Uma dica: você pode fazer tabelas no StackExchange; se quiser, posso fazê-las para você. E algumas observações: sou brasileiro e sempre falei "zero gatos", achei que falassem "zero gato" em Portugal. E já que colocou "bilião ou bilhão", acho que faz sentido dizer "quatorze ou catorze", porque os 2 são ditos.

@Schilive, "zero gatos" em BR: uma amigo brasileiro garantiu-me que usava "zero gato"; ver também https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/artigos/rubricas/idioma/zero-com-ou-sem-plural/2837 dependerá da região?

Vendo no Corpus do português e sites sobre gramática, está certo! Deve ser regional, mesmo.

Mais um brasileiro aqui que usa e ouve "zero gatoS".

@stafusa e @ shilive obrigado pela informação. Vou juntar "gato ou gatos" admitindo que as duas sejam usadas.
